# String "a" is not equal to Char "a" in C#?

Tags: c#, string, char

So, I'm having one algorithm for parsing expressions. Also, there are conditional ways to go, whether there are brackets or not. I'm making expression and putting it in string variable, like:

```
string expression = "6*(3+2)";
```

and then I let it to go through parsing function. After it was giving me weird result, I went to debug parse function and noticed weird thing going out there:
as I was iterating through characters of string from right to left with

```
for (int i = (expression.Length -1); i>=0; i--) ...
```

it didn't pass through condition

```
if (expression[i].Equals(")")) ...
```

when in expression[i] was showing on ")", because I saw it on "Locals" part in Visual Studio.
Why is that?
How I needed to do is:

```
if (expression[i].ToString() == ")") ...
```

and then I would be getting correct results. It didn't let me to do expression[i] == ")" because it said that I can't apply "==" operator on char and string.

So, why .Equals didn't pass when it was ")"?

Comment: Two things of distinct data types cannot be considered the same thing even if they *look* the same.

Comment: So why doesn't OP get a type error here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why is that?

Characters aren't the same as strings. A string is a *sequence* of characters. The type of `expression[i]` is `char`, not `string` - so you want to compare it with a `char` literal:

```
if (expression[i] == ')')
```

Note the single quotes (`')'`) instead of the double quotes you were using (`")"`). Single quotes are used for character literals; double quotes are used for string literals.

Comment: <offtopic> Wow, Mr. Jon, very nice to get answer from you, saw your book and your comments, really nice to have you in this community :) </offtopic>. So in other words, expression[i].Equals(')') would be also correct. Thank you :)

Comment: @Tommz: You *could* use `Equals`, but personally I'd use `==` as per my answer.

Comment: char[i] == 'x' The quote should be single - Helpful Question & Answer

Comment: @JonSkeet What about if you want to do a != comparison like string[0] != '1'. Becuase it does not seem to work. Thanks

Comment: @omachu23: Yes it absolutely does work. It's unclear what you're actually doing, what you expected, or what happened. I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve].