# What is the problem with char equal to ","?

Tags: c#, equality

```
        string odp = "2,1";
        bool abs = odp[1].Equals(",");
```

When I do `Console.Writeline(odp[i])` it shows `","` symbol so why does it equal to false?

I tried using `==` instead but it *doesn't work either*. Thanks in advance

Comment: A `char` and a `String` are not the same type of object. What happens if you change `","` to `','`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String "a" is not equal to Char "a" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884040/string-a-is-not-equal-to-char-a-in-c)

Comment: *"it doesnt work"*. That is never an acceptable problem description. ALWAYS tell us what actually happens. It's not a specific issue in this case because the problem is obvious but that will not always be the case. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn what is required of a question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

A `Char` is encapsulated in single quotation marks `','` in C# (a `String` uses double quotation marks `","`).

Try the below instead:

```
string odp = "2,1";
bool abs = odp[1].Equals(','); // true
```

Comment: ...or `bool abs = odp[1] == ',';`